# bash: redirectly subshell into read

Tags: bash, sh, nagios

A little history behind this - I'm trying to write a nagios plugin to detect if an nfs mount is unmounted and if a mount is stale, which is where I'm running into a problem.

What I'm trying to achieve is detecting if a mount is stale.  The problem I'm trying to work around is the fact that a stale nfs handle causes any action on that directory to hang and timeout after 3-4 minutes.  By forcing a timeout onto a stat command inside an nfs mounted directory with read, I should be able to work around that problem.

So I picked up this snippet somewhere, which works perfectly when run manually from the cli on an nfs client (where /www/logs/foo is a stale nfs mount)

```
$ read -t 2 < <(stat -t /www/logs/foo/*); echo $?
1
```

The problem comes when I try to incorporate this snippet into a script like so (snippet attached, full script attached at the end):

```
list_of_mounts=$(grep nfs /etc/fstab | grep -v ^# | awk '{print $2'} | xargs)
exitstatus $LINENO

for X in $list_of_mounts; do
    AM_I_EXCLUDED=`echo " $* " | grep " $X " -q; echo $?`
    if [ "$AM_I_EXCLUDED" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "" >> /dev/null
    #check to see if mount is mounted according to /proc/mounts
    elif [ ! `grep --quiet "$X " /proc/mounts; echo $?` -eq 0 ]; then
        #mount is not mounted at all, add to list to remount
        remount_list=`echo $remount_list $X`;
    #now make sure its not stale
    elif [ ! "`read -t 2  < <(stat -t $X/*) ; echo $?`" -eq "0" ]; then
        stalemount_list=`echo $stalemount_list $X`
    fi
```

Gives me this error:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfs_mounts.sh: command substitution: line 46: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfs_mounts.sh: command substitution: line 46: `read -t 2  < <( '
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfs_mounts.sh: command substitution: line 46: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfs_mounts.sh: command substitution: line 46: ` ) ; echo $?'
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nfs_mounts.sh: line 46: [: stat -t /www/logs/foo/*: integer expression expected
```

I was able to work around the syntax error by using "    read -t 2<<< $(stat -t $X/*)" instead of "    read -t 2< <(stat -t $X/*)", however stat no longer benefits from the timeout on read, which takes me back to the original problem.

While I'm open to new solutions, I'm also curious as to what behavior might be causing this shell vs script difference.

Full nagios check:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "
    Usage:
    check_nfs_mounts.sh
    It just works.
    Optional: include an argument to exclude that mount point
"
}
ok() {
        echo "OK - $*"; exit 0
        exit
}
warning() {
        echo "WARNING - $*"; exit 1
        exit
}
critical() {
        echo "CRITICAL - $*"; exit 2
        exit
}
unknown() {
        echo "UNKNOWN - $*"; exit 3
        exit
}
exitstatus() {
        if [ ! "$?" -eq "0" ] ;
        then unknown "Plugin failure - exit code not OK - error line $*"
        fi
}
# Get Mounts
list_of_mounts=$(grep nfs /etc/fstab | grep -v ^# | awk '{print $2'} | xargs)
exitstatus $LINENO

for X in $list_of_mounts; do
    AM_I_EXCLUDED=`echo " $* " | grep " $X " -q; echo $?`
    if [ "$AM_I_EXCLUDED" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "" >> /dev/null
    #check to see if mount is mounted according to /proc/mounts
    elif [ ! `grep --quiet "$X " /proc/mounts; echo $?` -eq 0 ]; then
        #mount is not mounted at all, add to list to remount
        remount_list=`echo $remount_list $X`;
    #now make sure its not stale
    elif [ ! "`read -t 2  <<< $(stat -t $X/*) ; echo $?`" -eq "0" ]; then
        stalemount_list=`echo $stalemount_list $X`
    fi
done
#Make sure result is a number
if [ -n "$remount_list" ] && [ -n "$stalemount_list" ];  then
    critical "Not mounted: $remount_list , Stale mounts: $stalemount_list"
elif [ -n "$remount_list" ] && [ -z "$stalemount_list"]; then
    critical "Not mounted: $remount_list"
elif [ -n "$stalemount_list" ] && [ -n "$remount_list" ]; then
    critical "Stale mount: $stalemount_list"
elif [ -z "$stalemount_list" ] && [ -z "$remount_list" ]; then
    ok "All mounts mounted"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your shebang specifies Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The reason for the error message is that on your system, Bash is symlinked to `/bin/sh` which is used when there's no shebang or when it's `#!/bin/sh`.

In this case, Bash is run as if you had started it with `bash --posix` which disables *some* non-POSIX features such as process substitution (`<()`), but confusingly not others such as here strings (`<<<`).

Change your shebang and you should be OK.

Comment: Verified that it was simply a bash vs sh issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the output of a subshell in this way:

```
$ read a < <(echo one)
$ echo $a
one
```

Or in this way (if you just want to process $a and forget it:

```
$ ( echo one; echo two) | (read a; echo $a)
one
```

The first variant will work only in `bash`. Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`) does not support this syntax. May be that is the reason why you get the error message. May be you script is interpreted by `/bin/sh` not by `/bin/bash`